# DocumentDb write within a transactionscope

Tags: c#, .net, azure, transactionscope, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to use a DocumentDb write as a part of a transaction like below -

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope)
{
//first transaction

//write to document db

//third transaction
}
```

I observed that if the third transaction fails, documentDb write is not rolled back and I still see the document in the collection. The first transaction (NEventStore in this case) rolls back perfectly. Does anyone know if DocumentDb supports TrnasactionScope. What if I have a nested transaction?

Thanks!

Edit:
So looks like TransactionScope is not supported with DocumentDb and it knows nothing about them. Is there a way to make DocumentDb transactions part of an external transaction from C#? Has anyone come across this use case before?

Edit 2: Follow-up question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31826887/documentdb-transactions-as-a-part-of-an-external-transaction-scope) as suggested

Comment: Even with your edited question, the answer remains the same as what I posted: there are no external transaction mechanisms, only the sproc-scoped transaction. Note: It's not really good form to change the context of your question after getting an answer to your question. Better to ask a new question.

Comment: Sure. I will open up a new question to explore that context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DocumentDB operations are independent from `TransactionScope`. Once an operation returns, it's done. The database service doesn't know anything about `TransactionScope` and isn't connected to it in any way.

DocumentDB does have a transaction scope of its own, when working with server-side stored procedures. You can have multiple database calls within the stored proc, and if everything is successful, there's an implicit commit upon the stored procedure exiting. If something goes wrong and an exception is thrown, an implicit rollback is executed for all operations performed to the database within the stored procedure's scope.

Comment: Thanks! is there a way around this problem?

Comment: The only way around it is to use DocumentDB's Stored Procedures as @David suggests.

Comment: So my transaction scope is not limited to documentDb but there are external pieces (line NEventStore) which are part of this transaction.

Comment: The best approach for doing this is to implement compensation logic in your application on Rollback of your distributed transaction. If your external pieces fail after your DocumentDB stuff has completed, then execute a compensating action to "rollback" the database.

Comment: @RyanCrawCour-MSFT What happens when the rollback operations fail?

Comment: Also, what happens if we need a transaction across partitions?

Comment: As hinted at by @TimGabrhel's question, writing compensating logic is very hard to get right the first time and it's almost impossible to maintain as your business logic evolves. That's why ACID constraints were introduced. So, if you can get away with single-partition ACID, use stored procedures. Otherwise, you might want to consider an alternative to DocumentDB. IMHO, I think compensating logic is worth it only when you must deal with an external API beyond your control

Answer (score 0):

Lots of SQL users don't understand what to do where transactions are not available.

You should implement compensation logic your own or use frameworks like Windows Workflow Foundation. Compensation logic is related to Enterprise Integration Patterns. You also may use correlation ID pattern to check if big operation was done.

SQL people manage big operations in the same way when it is necessary to make long running transaction.
[https://www.amazon.com/Enterprise-Integration-Patterns-Designing-Deploying/dp/0321200683/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1480917322&sr=8-1&keywords=integration+patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321200683)