# DocumentDb transactions as a part of an external transaction scope

Tags: c#, .net, transactionscope, azure-cosmosdb

Is there a way to make DocumentDb transactions part of an external transaction from C#?

This is a follow-up question from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31819243/documentdb-write-within-a-transactionscope) and failure in transaction 3 below should rollback any documentDb updates.

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope)
{
//first transaction

//write to document db

//third transaction
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by implementing [IEnlistmentNotification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.ienlistmentnotification(v=vs.110).aspx) on DocumentDbRepository interacting with DocumentDb n the following way -

1. Implement the interface
2. Make the current instance part of the Transaction.Current in the constructor. (Or before any update if you are using dependency injection and object are created beforehand. Using Lazy<> can also be considered for constructor invocation during the transaction.
3. During create/update - save the old document, or the fact that the new object was created and save the selfLink.
4. If Rollback is called, take corrective action with the information saved in the step above.

PS - I can share the pseudo code if anyone is interested, please leave a comment.

Comment: Pseudo code would be pretty cool. What would be even cooler would be a GitHub project with actual code :)

Comment: Sure. Let me come up with a sample application to demonstrate this.

Comment: Did you create a GitHub project or pseudo code for this?